# Inverse Homography

Tags: c++, opencv, projection, perspective, homography

I get an H matrix using findHomography function.

```
H = findHomography(points_src, points_dst);
```

Then, I use H with warpPerspective to get a perspective projection of the image

```
warpPerspective(im_src, im_dst, H, Size(100, 100));
```

and from here I get a set of points of interest

```
vector<Point2f> points = some_function(im_dst)
```

Now I want to get back only the set of "points" to the original image and in this way I will now the set of points of interest in the original image.

For this task, I guess that I need to use again warpPerspective with the flag WARP_INVERSE_MAP but this does not work.

Answer (score 20):

You could indeed use `findHomography()` once again, but thanks to the [composition properties of such matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Composing_and_inverting_transformations), a much more elegant, accurate and fast way to reverse the transformation is to simply **inverse the homography matrix**.

Here is a little demonstration using Python:

```python
import cv2
import numpy as np

source = np.float32([[0, 0], [100, 0], [100, 100], [0, 100]])
dest = np.float32([[0, 0], [-1000, 0], [-1000, -1000], [0, -1000]])

points = np.float32([[[50, 50]]])

homography, _ = cv2.findHomography(source, dest)

transformed = cv2.perspectiveTransform(points, homography)

print(transformed)
# => [[[-500. -500.]]]

homography_inverse = np.linalg.inv(homography)

detransformed = cv2.perspectiveTransform(transformed, homography_inverse)

print(detransformed)
# => [[[50. 50.]]]
```

Comment: cv also have builtin function for matrix inverse: `cv::Mat::inv`.

Answer (score 7):

To find the inverse homography, simply switch `points_dst` and `points_src`:

```
H_inv= findHomography(points_dst, points_src);
```

Then if you apply the `H_inv` to the points trandformed by `H`, you will obtain the original points.